# Adding additional user information to a website using ASP.NET MVC 4 and System.Web.Providers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have set up ASP.NET MVC 4 with System.Web.Providers, and now I would like to add some more user information, like address, birthdate, etc.

I would also like to relate the existing user data from Providers to post, such that each post has an author from the Providers.

I must be such that when a user creates a post, everything about the user must be (lazily) available from selecting that post.

I was maybe thinking about having a User class containing the `UserProfile` class from the standard MVC template project (which seems to be used with the HTTP login), and the `aspnet_users` from the providers, but I am not really sure how to go about this.

What is the common way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to go with `Providers`. These are available in *ASP.NET* for a very long time, and still used. Their implementation is the same for both (*WebForms* and *MVC*) so I would suggest to read this comprehensive tutorial about them

- https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx by Scott Mitchell

The `Profile` feature is exactly the place for user specific information. It can be extended easily and represents the extension point to `Membership`. We are using our one `Profile` class:

```
public class ProjectProfile : ProfileBase 
{
    // TODO custom properties 
}
```

configured in web.config

```
<profile defaultProvider="ProjectProfile" 
         inherits="MyLibrary.ProjectProfile, MyLibrary">
  <providers >
  <clear/>
  <add name="ProjectProfile" type="MyLibrary.ProjectProfileProvider, MyLibrary" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

So, the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProjectProfile` has the information needed.

Comment: Do I need to wire up the MVC class `UserProfile` to the `Providers` or is this done automatically?

Comment: `UserProfile` derived from `ProfileBase` must be specified in *web.config*. Later it is available even from `ControllerContext.HttpContext.Profile` (or filterContext in AOP). It must be cast to UserProfile to access its specific properties. I have great experience with this approach. It uses built in ASP.NET stuff, while giving me so much flexibility to extend profile...

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/storing-additional-user-information-cs) should give you all the info to implement your ProfileProvider

As suggested in the post (they go with the third option) and also in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1044531/394028), you should consider implementing your own logic to bind the profile to the currently active user

I use a profile class and extend the MembershipUser'one to implement my class. In that way I can access it with something like that:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser();
var profile = user.Profile;
```